# neo4j: Having a string in a query that looks like a math operation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

probably a silly question but cant figure it out:
A property of a Node is : 1-4567655

I assume that the query

```
MATCH (t:Ticket {number:"1-4567655"}) return t
```

fails cause neo4j calculates 1 Minus 4567655 which does not match of course. If thats the reason how can I query for that property though? I tried e.g.

```
MATCH (t:Ticket {number:toString(1-556264051)}) RETURN t
```

but this doesnt do the job either. Anyone have an idea how to search for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you do this query:

```
MATCH (t:Ticket {number:"1-4567655"}) return t
```

Neo4J will definitely **not** do the math and actually end up with the string -4567654 (which is what you'd get if you did the math).  No, you're literally specifying a regular string whose value is "1-4567655".   So if this query returns nothing, the most likely reason is because you don't have a `Ticket` node that has that number.

You can do simple math in Neo4j.  The query `RETURN 10-2` gives you the answer 8.  When I run `return 1-556264051;` I get `-556264050`.   Using `toString` on that works fine too.   So once again, I think your database is actually missing a `Ticket` node that has a number property with that value.

Is it possible that the `number` property is a different type (Long or Double) and not a string?

For example, I did this:

```
create (t:Ticket {number: 1});
```

If you try to match it with:  `MATCH (t:Ticket { number: "1" }) return t` you'll get nothing.  Because the string `"1"` and the number `1` are not the same thing.

Try to change your queries to look for numbers (not strings) and I'm betting that's going to help.

Comment: Awesome. Seems I lack here on knowledge. When I try the query without quotation marks the ticket is find <<MATCH (t:Ticket {number:1-4567655}) RETURN t>> - this works now. When I want to query another property e.g. like status I still need to query like <<MATCH (t:Ticket {status:"Closed"}) RETURN t>>. Is it that the property for number is somehow not a string? If so how would I define this property to be definitive a string while creating it in order to avoid this? I just use set t.number = csvLine[1]. Maybe I need to set the type too? Thanks for your help, its very appreciated.

Comment: When importing via CSV, just use toString() if you'd like to guarantee that's a string.